# Trying to filter same column twice in query using regexp with different patterns

Tags: php, mysql

I am fairly new to mysql and php queries beyond basic SELECT * FROM blah WHERE blah, so I'm pretty hung up on something here. I'm trying to browse photos based on weather conditions and moon phase. Right now, the weather, the moon phases, and photos are stored in 3 different tables, and all 3 store date differently. This is out of my control for weather and moon phases, as they are based on a 3rd party api.

Anyway, here's my current query:

```
$pics = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE cam_id IN ($cams)";
    if($moon == 1){ $pics .= " AND photo_date REGEXP '$phase_dates'";}
    if($cond == 1){ $pics .= " AND photo_date REGEXP '$cond_dates'";}
```

The data for both $phase_dates and $cond_dates are imploded arrays using this code:

```
$cond_dates = implode("|",$cond_date);
$phase_dates = implode("|",$phase_date);
```

The only difference is $cond_dates needs to be more specific as weather conditions are tracked every 20 minutes, whereas the moon phase is once a day. Because of that, I use:

```
date('Y:m:d H', $cdate);
```

for the $cond_date, and I use:

```
date('Y:m:d',$pdate);
```

for $phase_date.

That returns 2016:11:16 09 for conditions, and 2016:11:16 for phase. My query ends up like:

```
$pics = "SELECT * FROM photos 
WHERE cam_id 
IN ($cams) 
AND photo_date REGEXP '2016:11:16|2016:11:17' 
AND photo_date REGEXP '2016:11:16 09|2016:11:16 10|2016:11:17 09'";
```

But even when it matches, I get no results. When both date sets use Y:m:d, I get matches, but when I add the hour, no results. Is there a way to get matches, without losing the specificity of the hour?

Answer (score 0):

It won't match because photo_date won't be 2016:11:16 and 2016:11:17 at the same time. What you need to use here is `OR` operator. So the query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM photos 
WHERE cam_id 
IN ($cams) 
AND (photo_date REGEXP '2016:11:16|2016:11:17' 
OR photo_date REGEXP '2016:11:16 09|2016:11:16 10|2016:11:17 09');
```

Comment: The AND works for me when I don't have the hour added after the date. Also, I need to use AND mainly because I'm looking for photos that match both sets of conditions.